# Exception Error while sending file to the S3 bucket on iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I am working on Unity SDK to send a csv file from my device to the S3 bucket using PutObject method with the example aws has share for uploading file to s3 bucket. The script works fine for the android but for ios i get error stating execption while uploading file, whereas downloading a file from S3 works fine on both.

pls find the code attached to this link - https://jpst.it/1aNCU
The code is same as suggested in the aws-unity-sdk S3 Example file

Suggestion Appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think u given wrong s3 bucket name or key name or else could u pls share code

Comment: The bucketname and key is correct! pls find the code attached to this link - https://jpst.it/1aNCU

Comment: @everyone pls support me with the ios aws-unity-sdk